# AngularJS returned 404 error if I typed the URL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an angularjs application hosted in my local IIS with route configured. For example '/services' will use `servicesController` and `services.partial.html` view.

It worked well if I clicked the link on the main page and the browser address changed to `http://localhost/services`. But if I refresh or type this URL directly I got 404 error.

Can anyone help me what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you refresh or type you page, the entire page while be reloaded out of angular's control, in fact its the browser that is taking control. thus you localhost have to return a valid resource for /services. without html being returned, there is no way angular can control the behavior of the route.

basically what you should do is config you server and return the same page for /services as /

Comment: I checked SO and found this solution on Apache that can handle all request from your root path. I know I can implement in IIS through url rewrite but just wanted to check if any build-in function IIS could support likes Apache.

Comment: @ShaunXu Do you happen to know how to configure this with Oracle WLS ? Any info would be helpful to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://localhost/#/services` instead of `http://localhost/services` and this would work fine as I see.

Comment: Yes this is what I heard but the address changed back to `http://localhost/services` automatically even I set the route to `/#/services` and when I refreshed same behaviour.